# What's the best way of displaying PDF/Excel/Docx Documents From Localhost In Android App

Tags: php, android, excel, pdf, webview

I'm writing an Android App which can connect to our own localhost with localhost ip (example: `http://192.168.1.200`). I want to display some PDF, XLS, XLSX and DOC files from the app. So, which choices I have:

Linking the document url directly from the app: This is not the way I want. Because it's starting to download file and open it with another app (office viewer, etc).

Opening it from WebView: This is the same as above option.

Opening it from **Google Docs**: Google docs is NOT showing file from local URL.

Using android-pdfview: Maybe this is a good choice but it is ONLY PDF. Not XLSX and other files.

Using PHPExcel: PHPExcel is a good PHP library for reading files but it is not showing the documents directly. It only reads the lines, cells, etc.

I couldn't find any solution. What should I do?

Comment: You realise that PHPExcel can read an Excel file and generate HTML from that file using the HTML Writer? Meaning that if you can render HTML markup in a browser on android, you can display it. Alternatively, you can also generate a PDF from that file

Comment: Likewise, PHPWord can also generate either HTML or PDF

Comment: Do you have any example code for generating html from pdf/xlsx with phpexcel?

Comment: I'm sure there's an example in the examples folder; but it's only about 5 lines of code.... load file to $objPHPExcel; instantiate HTML Writer with $objPHPExcel; call Writer's save method.